# How to delete items by ID-s of their child item in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to write an JPQL query which would delete all `PlaylistItem`-s refering to specific `ArtContent`-s by `ArtContent` IDs.

I tried this:

```
public int deleteItemsByContentIds(Long[] contentIds) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    int result = em.createQuery(
    "delete from PlaylistItem where artContent.id in (:idsArray) ")
    .setParameter("idsArray", contentIds).executeUpdate();

    return result;
}
```

but it throws an exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet RemoveContentServlet threw exception: 
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.Long]
```

What is understandable, because there is no `setParameter` method taking an array as an argument. So what is the best way to solve such an issue?

Simplified class definition:

```
@Entity
public class PlaylistItem implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private int position;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "PLAYLIST_ID")
private Playlist playlist;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ART_CONTENT_ID")
private ArtContent artContent;

...
```

}

```
@Entity
public class ArtContent implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep using `.setParameter` but you need to make the value extend a Collection (like an ArrayList) instead of using an array type.  Maybe just change to:

```
public int deleteItemsByContentIds(Long[] contentIds) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    int result = em.createQuery(
    "delete from PlaylistItem where artContent.id in (:idsArray) ")
    .setParameter("idsArray", Arrays.asList(contentIds)).executeUpdate();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `setParameterList` instead.

Edit:

Sorry, for JPA convert it to a Collection (`Arrays.asList(arrayOfLongs)`) and just use `setParameter`.

Edit 2: Beaten to the punch!

Comment: Thanks, but setParameterList is a method of org.hibernate.Query and here I have javax.persistence.Query.

Comment: Yes, the Collection did the job :)